# Singularity in np.sqrt

Tags: python, numpy, sqrt

Strange RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in sqrt

I am working in a task in which I take the positions of a huge amount of particles (128**3) from hdf5 file and then calculate the relative distance between them.

Running the code, I detected an unexpected RuntimeWarning in sqrt function. Working over the code, I isolate the problem in the following lines:

```
#This lines presented the problem
((Pos-Pos[0])[:,0]**2)
np.sqrt(((Pos-Pos[0])[:,0]**2))

#This lines do not present the problem
((Pos-Pos[0])[:,0]**2)[1:]
np.sqrt(((Pos-Pos[0])[1:,0]**2)[1:])

#This lines do not present the problem
((Pos-Pos[0])[:,0]**2)[:100]
np.sqrt(((Pos-Pos[0])[:,0]**2)[:100])

#My proposition to solve it
((Pos-Pos[0])[:,0]**2)
np.sqrt(((Pos-Pos[0])[:,0]**2)+1e-10)
```

I do not understand very well the nature of this trouble. Could you help me to understand this better?

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO. But... what is `Pos`? It helps to provide a [mcve] that reproduces your problem.

Comment: Sorry, you are right. Pos is a ndarray which shape is (128**3,3) and contains values between -0.5 and 0.5.